# Retrieving string from List

Tags: android

I am using a third party library to show dates on a custom calendar.

I need to retrieve some information when the user clicks on a day.

This is the code for onDayClick method:

```
 public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {
                List<Event> events = compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked);
                Log.d(TAG, "Day was clicked: " + dateClicked + " with events " + events);


            }
```

And this is the output from the log for this method:

```
Day was clicked: Wed Mar 13 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019 with events [Event{color=-16711936, timeInMillis=1552431600000, data=Some extra data that I want to store.}]
```

I would like to retrieve the field data from that string...

Comment: Can you post an example of a current output? just to see what you are passing under "data" with a real demo

Comment: Post more information about the library you are using. This will help understand how they are storing the data.

Comment: @hardartcore should be [that one](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView); data is of type Object; for this I would like to see an actual example of data :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley, you are right, but I have modified some parts and I only need to retrieve this data field for my project

Comment: yeah I just wanted a real example to see what kind of result you are getting from a real log on your device. is it possible?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley, the log result is shown in my question: Day was clicked: Wed Mar 13 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2019 with events [Event{color=-16711936, timeInMillis=1552431600000, data=Some extra data that I want to store.}]

Comment: oh ok, awkard.. I thought it would add some double quotes for that "Some extra data that I want to store". thanks!

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley, it is already solved by AlexTa

Comment: seen, good! and good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According `CompactCalendarView` library, data object type is `Object`. So, to retrieve that field, just iterate through event list, then access data field:

```
List<Event> events = compactCalendarView.getEvents(dateClicked);
for (Event event : events) {
    Object data = event.getData();
    // Access to other event properties
    int color = event.getColor();
    long timeInMillis = event.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what type is Data? I am getting some options, but none is working.

Comment: and event.data is never recognized as valid expression

Comment: Type of data is Object, to access that property just invoke event.getData()